# Is it possible share the RawValue between two instances of role for Performance Counter?

Tags: c#, azure, performancecounter, azure-diagnostics

With Azure, we have a worker role, which assigned two instances. Inside of them, we have a Performance Counter to record the count of some operation:

```
static Service()
{
    Counter = new PerformanceCounter(CustomCounterCategory, CustomCounterName, "instance", false);
}

public static void DoSomething()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("[{0}]Raw value is {1}", RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id, Counter.RawValue);
        Counter.Increment();
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    }
}
```

Above demo code just read current raw data of performance counter and log it, then increment by one.

From the logging, I found the raw data for different instances is exactly same: `0, 1, 2, 3 ...`. So any way to share the raw data for two instances, making the performance counter exists across different instances of role?

#### UPDATE

Here is how I create the performance counter category:

```
if (!PerformanceCounterCategory.Exists(Service.CustomCounterCategory))
{
    var counterCollection = new CounterCreationDataCollection();

    var operationTotal1 = new CounterCreationData
    {
        CounterName = Service.CustomCounterName,
        CounterHelp = "help",
        CounterType = PerformanceCounterType.NumberOfItems32
    };

    counterCollection.Add(operationTotal1);
    PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(
        Service.CustomCounterCategory, 
        "CategoryDescription",
        PerformanceCounterCategoryType.MultiInstance, 
        counterCollection);
}
```

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2004/10/29/249799.aspx

Answer (score 0):

See this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn535595.aspx

```
PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(
     "MyCustomCounterCategory",
     "My Custom Counter Category",
     PerformanceCounterCategoryType.SingleInstance, counterCollection);

   Trace.WriteLine("Custom counter category created.");
```

try changing the singleInstance to other options. Sure there will be option for multiinstance also

Comment: @JerryBian according to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2004/10/29/249799.aspx you should use `PerformanceCounterCategoryType.SingleInstance` to achieve one system-wide counter.

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair the deployment would fail once I change `MultiInstance` to  `SingleInstance` ... something like `PdhExpandWildCardPath(\CustomCounterCategory3(instance)\CustomCounterName3) failed`

Comment: @JerryBian did you investigate if Azure is capable of multiInstance counters?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair I did a google search, but not found meaningful resources. And that's why I post a thread in SO. :-)

Comment: @JerryBrian there's a [walkthrough](http://blog.isaleem.com/2013/12/azure-custom-performance-counters.html) available - does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Shortly answer: **NO**.

Just in case you're looking for the answer of same question.